# How to do this in Laravel, subquery

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

> How can I make this query in Laravel:

```
select users.username,users.photo, questions.*,
 (Select count(*) from answers 
 where answers.q_id=questions.id) as aAccount from questions
INNER JOIN users ON users.id=questions.user_id
```

Comment: What have you tried doing so far? Are you asking how to do it using Eloquent, or just by [running raw SQL queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries)?

Comment: i want to convert this query into laravel query

Comment: What models do you have?

Comment: i do it using Eloquent

Comment: three models i have

Comment: User, Question , Answer Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use db raw for all query or DB::connection()->select()->join()->join()->query('subqueryz')->where()->orderBy()

Second option is best.

Comment: please you explain bit more i try but i can't understand

Comment: You can use first option:  DB fasade. `DB::connection('name_connection_is_in_config_database')->select(DB::raw('YOUR CUSTOM ALL SELECT WHERE name = ? ORDER BY.....'), [$name]);`    or you can use `DB::connection()->table('table_name')->select('column names')->from('table name')->join('second table name')->get()`. Here is documentation abou database query [https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)